# What does percentage mean in the following most trivial html?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#container 
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
body
{
  outline: green solid 1px;
}
p.bottommargin 
{
  outline: green solid 1px;
  margin-bottom:1%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph with no margin specified.</p>
<div id="container">
<p class="bottommargin">This is a paragraph with a specified bottom margin.</p>
</div>
<p>This is a paragraph with no margin specified.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

It is clearly 1% of neither the `<p>` nor the `<div>` nor the `<body>` elements. So, what is it?

The sample is available here - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/SJjaV/

Thanks.

**P.S.**

I am very new to the web programming, so I beg your pardon if my question is really stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the CSS 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

Thus it is 1% of the width of `#container`

[[image: Diagram showing the above is accurate]
embiggen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua288.png)